# Mysql Join 4 tables with empty rows

Tags: mysql, join

I try to join 4 tables,

1. item_list
2. item
3. item_image
4. item_table

the problem is, 
I want item that have rows in item table, it easy, I can INNER JOIN both,
but the rest for image and table, I don't care if item has images or table, so I use LEFT JOIN.

Here's the relations :

(item_list)--One to Many--(item)

(item_list)--One to Many--(item_image)

(item_list)--One to Many--(item_table)

So this the query :

```
SELECT * FROM item_list 
   INNER JOIN item ON item.item_list_id = item_list.id 
   LEFT JOIN item_image ON item_image.item_list_id = item_list.id 
   LEFT JOIN item_table ON item_table.item_list_id = item_list.id 
WHERE item_list.is_featured = '1' 
  AND item_table.is_deleted = '0' 
  AND item.is_deleted = '0' 
  AND item_image.is_deleted = '0' 
  AND item_list.is_deleted = '0' 
  AND item_table.language_id = '1' 
  AND item.language_id = '1' 
ORDER BY item_list.id DESC
```

and this query only return rows that have ALL OF THEM,
so, if an item that doesn't have images or table, it doesn't fetched.

Comment: That is because you added conditions to your where clause that make your LEFT JOIN pure joins. `AND item_table.is_deleted = '0'` and  `AND item_image.is_deleted = '0'` and `AND item_table.language_id = '1'`

Comment: It can only filters on Existing rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that the conditions in the WHERE clause are restricting the results.

For the tables that you want optionally, you should move those conditions to the ON section of the FROM clause.

```
SELECT * FROM item_list 
   INNER JOIN item ON item.item_list_id = item_list.id 
   LEFT JOIN item_image ON item_image.item_list_id = item_list.id 
      AND item_image.is_deleted = '0' 
   LEFT JOIN item_table ON item_table.item_list_id = item_list.id 
      AND item_table.is_deleted = '0' 
      AND item_table.language_id = '1' 
WHERE item_list.is_featured = '1' 
  AND item.is_deleted = '0' 
  AND item_list.is_deleted = '0' 
  AND item.language_id = '1' 
ORDER BY item_list.id DESC
```

This is because the WHERE clause is applied for every record in the join, regardless if it brought data or not. But it seems that you actually want to filter down on that data only with certain conditions.

An approach is to conditionally check for those, as @Dhiraj Katekar suggested, but you can also move those conditions to the JOINs as I suggested and they should have a very similar effect.

Answer (score 1):

AND (**item_image.is_deleted = '0'  or item_image.is_deleted is null** ) AND item_list.is_deleted = '0' AND (**item_table.language_id = '1'  or item_table.language_id is null**)